# Using end in single step batch job in Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring-batch

We have configured batch job with single step. The general structure is like,

```
<batch:job id="mainJob">
    <batch:step id="step1">
        <batch:tasklet>
            <batch:chunk reader="fileReader" writer="jmsItemWriter" >
                <batch:retryable-exception-classes>
                    <batch:include class="org.springframework.dao.CannotAcquireLockException"/>
                </batch:retryable-exception-classes>
            </batch:chunk>
        </batch:tasklet>
        <batch:end on="UNKNOWN"/>
        <batch:next on="*" to="step1"/>
        <batch:listeners>
            <batch:listener ref="listener1"/>
            <batch:listener ref="listener2"/>
        </batch:listeners>

    </batch:step>
   <batch:listeners>
        <batch:listener ref="jobListener"/>
   </batch:listeners>
  </batch:job>
```

fileReader is FlatFileItemReader which reads a file line by line and passes each line to 'listener2'. In listener2, if there is error in the line it should set the status to 'unknown' (not failed, because the job should not be started again) and then stop the job.

To accomplish this, we have.

```
<batch:end on="UNKNOWN"/>
<batch:next on="*" to="step1"/>
```

But the batch job doesn't end on Unknown and goes into the loop because of 'next'. There is an exception if 'next' is not mentioned.

How can we resolve this?

Edit:

Some more explanation for Dean's answer.

Listener2 gets FieldSet i.e. file entries line by line. While processing these entries, if some conditions (which involve database queries also) are met, the job should not read further file and stop. As the processing is done in override method 'mapFieldSet' which doesn't throw any exception, new exception can't be used and returning null just reads next line. Generally the files have thousands of line but within first 2 lines it is determined if further reading is necessary or not.

Comment: I've added more to the answer below based on your updates

Answer (score 0):

What you've done is pretty non-standard. Here's what I'd do...

- Remove Listener 2 (this is not really how errors should be handled)
- Do the validation work in an `ItemProcessor` instead of waiting for the JMS writer to fail
- Either throw an exception or return null from the processor for invalid items
- Create an Exception Listener (`StepExecutionListener`) that checks the Failure Exceptions and flips the `ExitStatus`

**Example step execution listener `afterStep` method:**

```
public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    for (Throwable t : stepExecution.getFailureExceptions()) {
        if ("EXPECTED MESSAGE".equals(t.getMessage())) {
            return ExitStatus.UNKNOWN;
        }
     }
    return null;
}
```

---

**UPDATE Based on New Info In Question:**

From what you've indicated, it seems like a `Decider` might actually be your cleanest solution.

**Modification to job flow:**

```
<batch:job id="mainJob">
    <batch:decision id="decision" decider="someDecider">
        <next on="PROCESS" to="step1" />
        <end on="STOP" />
        <fail on="*" />
    </batch:decision>
    <batch:step id="step1">
        <!-- . . . -->
    </batch:step>
    <!-- . . . -->
</batch:job>
```

**Example `Decider` Class:**

```
public class ProcessFileDecider implements JobExecutionDecider {

    private Resource resource;

    @Override
    public FlowExecutionStatus decide(final JobExecution jobExecution, final StepExecution stepExecution) {
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(resource.getInputStream()))) {
            final String lineOne = reader.readLine();
            final String lineTwo = (lineOne != null) ? reader.readLine() : null;

            final boolean processFile = true; //some logic here
            if (processFile) {
                return new FlowExecutionStatus("PROCESS");
            }
            return new FlowExecutionStatus("STOP");

        } catch (final IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Hit error deciding whether to process the resource!", e);
        }
    }

    public void setResource(Resource resource) {
        this.resource = resource;
    }

}
```

Comment: Updated question for your suggestions.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. This does look like the cleanest solution. I will try it and update here.

Comment: that worked very well and with custom exit-status, I could log proper message too. Thanks again.